# Angular CLI service worker error on stratup

Tags: angular, progressive-web-apps, angular-service-worker, angular-pwa

I started new Angular 8 project with those specs:

```
Angular CLI: 8.0.4
Node: 10.16.0
OS: darwin x64
Angular: 8.0.2
```

Angular PWA:

```
ng add @angular/pwa
```

package.json

```
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "~8.0.1",
    "@angular/common": "~8.0.1",
    "@angular/compiler": "~8.0.1",
    "@angular/core": "~8.0.1",
    "@angular/forms": "~8.0.1",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "~8.0.1",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "~8.0.1",
    "@angular/pwa": "^0.800.4",
    "@angular/router": "~8.0.1",
    "@angular/service-worker": "~8.0.1",
    "rxjs": "~6.4.0",
    "tslib": "^1.9.0",
    "zone.js": "~0.9.1"
  },
```

**I have 2 error in console on startup. How can I fix it?**

> A bad HTTP response code (404) was received when fetching the script.
> service-worker.js.pre-build-optimizer.js:451
>
> Service worker
> registration failed with: TypeError: Failed to register a
> ServiceWorker: A bad HTTP response code (404) was received when
> fetching the script.

Answer (score 1):

If you are trying to test this locally with the CLI, the service worker will throw this error. You need to test following [these instructions](https://angular.io/guide/service-worker-getting-started#service-worker-in-action-a-tour).

Further, if not on localhost, browsers reject service workers over insecure connections (http vs https) see [here](https://angular.io/guide/service-worker-intro#prerequisites).

Comment: Actually, no. With localhost everything should be fine ( "There is one exception to this rule: To make local development easier, browsers do not require a secure connection when accessing an app on localhost." - https://angular.io/guide/service-worker-intro ). I tried before version 7, and there were no errors. Did you personaly tried version 8?

Comment: I mean locally explicitly with the CLI (ng serve). You need to serve it locally with something different to test. In those instructions I linked, they use the http-server package. I have a service worker in different projects with 7 as well as 8.

If this is what you are doing, please update your post with your configuration and how you are registering in your module.

Comment: My confs are default - nothing more than mentioned in the description above. The project was created with "ng new ProjectName". Now I uploaded this app to the firebase server (it has https), there are no errors, but the app, like before, for example, doesnt show me the pop-up message - "Add ProjectName to Home screen". Its even impossible to choose something similar in the Chrome´s menu from the right upper corner.

Comment: Are you checking on iOS? It won't work there. Also, firebase might have some caveats. A cursory search brought up many articles on angular service workers on firebase

Comment: I changed a version to a 8.0.2 and its fine ..Works on Mac, and on Firebase as well. Thanks for your help!

Comment: I am glad you figured it out. Service workers are extremely frustrating!